# UIAlertController how add the tag value in obj c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uialertview

Using this for UIAlertView

```
- (void) alertStatus:(NSString *)msg :(NSString *)title :(int) tag
{
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title
                                                        message:msg
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    alertView.tag = tag;
    [alertView show];
}
```

But now UIAlertView get deprecated. change my code

```
 UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:title message:msg preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    UIAlertAction* MyAlert = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];
    [alertController addAction:MyAlert];
   [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Here how can pass this tag value

```
alertView.tag = tag;
```

Help how to pass the tag value in UIAlertController. Thanks advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`UIAlertController` is the `UIViewController` , so we need to assign the tag for view, soe use `alertController.view.tag`.

```
UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"sds" message:@"sdf" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
alertController.view.tag = tag;
UIAlertAction* MyAlert = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];
[alertController addAction:MyAlert];
[self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

**update**

```
UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"sds" message:@"sdf" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
alertController.view.tag = 3;
UIAlertAction* MyAlert = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                          {
                              // OK button tappped.
                              [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

                              }];

                          }];
[alertController addAction:MyAlert];
[self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex    this also deprecated how to fix tis.

Comment: @saravanar no need to use `UIAlertView` delegate. Use `UIAlertController` only instead of `UIAlertView`

Comment: how to use alertView clickedButtonAtIndex in UIAlertController in obj c

Comment: @saravanar - no we cant use , uialertview is the UIview, but UIAlertController is the controller , the methid is upgraded

Comment: can u say which delegate method is used for  uialertcontroller clickedButtonAtIndex , i wrote the code as u written but i need that delegate method.

Comment: @saravanar - are you seen `// OK button tappped.` in here you get the delegate action

Comment: In my app i done all are using  alertController.tag=@"Tagnumber", so i want to write code for all newly that why asked. thank u so much for ur help.

Answer (score 4):

create a property of `UIAlertController *alertController;`, then use this `alertController` where ever you want. set the tag like this

```
alertController.view.tag = <YOUR TAG VALUE>;
```

to get the tag of that **alertController**, when you click on **YES** on alertController

```
//OK button tapped.
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    NSInteger *tag = alertController.view.tag;
}];
```

Comment: Can u say how to get the button index UIAlertController for yes and button click.

Comment: if your are created a property of `UIAlertController`, where ever you want to get the index of that alertController, just do like this,  `NSInteger *tag = alertController.view.tag;`. If there is no tag you are set for the alert, default it might be 0.

Answer (score 1):

Have not any tag property in UIAlertController. You can use block for getting button action.

```
UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Alert"
                                                               message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Your message"]
                                                        preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
[alert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
            //NSLog(@"OK");
        }]];
[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

But you can use tag in this way-

```
alert.view.tag = 1;
```

Comment: Can u say how to get the button index UIAlertController for yes and button click.